# Unable to put TERM to .bashrc in Mac

Tags: bash

[Stevey](http://stevey-home.blogspot.com/) recommends to set the following command to .bashrc

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

I put the code to the top of my .bashrc and I have now a flashing black green terminal. The font color in my terminal switches from black to green and vice versa periodically.

**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the Mac's terminal app doesn't support 256 color.  See here: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=443769

From the same link, it looks like there may be other terminals that do.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh I see - I just posted an answer that had to do with login vs non-login shells. I guess I missed the point.